# What is this cable/device?

Tags: led, cables, plug

I hope I'm on the appropriate site.

Does anyone know what this thing is?

It has a mini mono plug.
The white square is slippery..but it is not covering double-sided tape.
A white LED did not light up when I plugged it into a mic input on my PC.
I thought there were little holes and it might be a mic but they are small indentations, not holes.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be anything, but maybe a piezo mic?

Comment: When I plugged it into a PC I tried to record with it...but nothing.  And why the LED?

Comment: I've seen similar things before used to put remote photodiodes on a remote-operated device. I have one on an HDMI splitter and it uses the same connector. I can't say for sure, but I'm guessing the LED is a photodiode (or an LED being used as a photodiode) and this is meant to be plugged into one very specific device and nothing else. A picture showing the "LED" might be a good idea, by the way.

Comment: The bottom picture includes the LED.  Maybe I should have angled the shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an infrared transmitter for extenders or control systems. That plastic chunk with the IR LED gets glued on a device like TV or Blu-Ray player so that it shines on the device's IR receiver.

Comment: Thanks!   I guess I can throw it in my junk cables box.